Update The period in GSTR1 window In Tally Prime programmatically
I want to update the period in the GSTR1 export window.
I am using the Command below to set the current period in gateway of tally window using the below mentioned TDL and passing the parameters in the command Line. And this works. It updates the current period value in gateway Of tally window.
CMD Command:
"C:\Program Files\TallyPrime 4.1\tally.exe" "/TDL:D:\Comand Line\CommandLineTDL.txt" /LOAD:100001 /SETVAR:TempSVFromDate:20240405 /SETVAR:TempSVtoDate:20240410

TDL:
[System: Variable] Variable    : TempSVFromDate    : String        : "" Variable    : TempSVtoDate      : String        : "" [Function   : demoFunction] Return  : String 100 : Set       : SVFromDate    : $$Date:@@TempSVFromDate 120 : Set       : SV To Date    : $$Date:@@TempSVtoDate  140  : Return   : "Gateway of Tally" [#Menu:Gateway of Tally ] Title   : $$demoFunction [System: Formula] TempSVFromDate      : ##TempSVFromDate TempSVtoDate        : ##TempSVtoDate
But this does not change the period in GSTR1 export F2 window period.
Is there a way to achieve this using TDL or a command-line parameter? Any method to change the GSTR1 export window period to a specified value would be helpful.
Note:
To open GSTR1 Window

Open Company --> Gateway of tally --> Display more reports--> Statutory reports--GSTR-1--> Press F2

